# Ajuda com Código PHP e Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou precisando trazer somente os produtos referente a categoria selecionada, quando clico em:

```
<a class="cat-link" href="javascript:;" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>">
    <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);"
    src="img_cate/<?php echo $res['img_cat']; ?>" width="100"
    title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" />
</a>
```

Estou usando o código PHP abaixo,

```
<?php include "conexao.php"; ?>
<div id="produtos-content">
<!-- Listando os Categorias -->
<?php
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
$img_cat = $_POST['img_cat'];
$query_categoria = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_categoria)){
?>
<div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="cats-list">
        <a class="cat-link" href="javascript:;" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>">
            <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);"
            src="img_cate/<?php echo $res['img_cat']; ?>" width="100"
            title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" />
        </a>
        <div style="background:#2f2140; ; width:880px;z-index:999;border-radius:25px;" class="single-cat">
            <h1 align="center" style="width:830px; margin-top:-40px;"><?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?></h1>
            <div style="margin-left:357px;width:50px;" class="cat-links">
                <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                    <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
<?php
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$img_prod = $_POST['img_prod'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
$query_produtos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome_cat = '$nome_cat'") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_produtos)){
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="songs-list">
    <a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title="">
        <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="100" title="<?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>" />
        </a>

        <div style=" margin-top:120px;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:25px;border-top-right-radius:25px;" class="single-song">
        <div style="width:50px;margin-left:300px;" class="song-links">
            <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
            </a>
                <div class="song-sides">
                    <img style="margin:40px 0 0 -142px;" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="369" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <h1> <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?> </h1>
            <div class="entry" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100px;">
            <p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#ccc;">
            <?php echo nl2br($res['descricao']); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
            <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;">
            </div></div>
            </div>
            <span class="song-sides left-side"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

porem quando insiro o `WHERE nome_cat = '$nome_cat'` ele não me traz nada, mas quando o retiro, ele me traz todos os produtos listados na tabela PRODUTOS, independente da categoria selecionada.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e acho que estou precisando criar um manipulador de eventos, mas sou muito leigo em JavaScript.

Se os amigos puderem me dar essa ajuda, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Já deu um print_f em *$nome_cat* pra ver se tem realmente algo ?

Comment: A sua tag <a> precisa do atributo `name` e `value` para que esteja disponível no back-end.

Comment: Ola @Nevershowmyface, tem como você me dar um exemplo, pois sou realmente muito leigo em JavaScript.

Comment: @MuriloCabral adiciona o código do seu <form> completo. Em algum lugar precisa existir um <input> cujo atributo `name` seja `nome_cat`.

Comment: Pelo que vi no seu código, você não está enviando nada via POST. Faça o seguinte: No link, onde está href="javascript:;" coloque href="?nome_cat=<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" e onde você declara a variável $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];, coloque $nome_cat = $_GET['nome_cat'];

Comment: Olá @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, segui a sua orientação, e quase deu certo. Estou postando o endereço (**http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/**) para que vc possa verificar o que esta acontecendo depois da alteração. Pois quando seleciono uma categoria, ele me traz os produtos referente a categoria selecionada, porém rapidamente ele volta para o inicio. O que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: Ele volta para o início porque é feito um refresh na página. Pra resolver você faz o seguinte: Deixe a div .single-cat da seguinte maneira: <div style="background:#2f2140; ; width:880px;z-index:999;border-radius:25px; <?php echo $res['nome_cat']==$_GET['nome_cat'] ? 'display:block;' : ''; ?>" class="single-cat">

Comment: Show @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, funcionou do jeito que eu precisava, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Estarei postando o código que esta funcionando em uma resposta para que outros usuários com o mesmo problema possam ter a solução. Mais uma vez **BRIGADÃO MESMO**.

Comment: Veja no endereço **(http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/)** como esta funcionando apos a dica do amigo @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, a quem agradeço pela a ajuda.

Comment: Ok @Murilo Cabral, fico feliz em poder ajudar. Só gostaria de dar uma dica. Creio que a melhor solução para o que está fazendo seria utilizando ajax. Quando puder, dê uma pesquisadinha sobre como usar o $.get, $.post, $.ajax do jQuery blz. Até +

Comment: Valeu por mais essa dica @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, vou dar uma estudada sim, pois como podes ver estou tentando aprender e me aventurando nesse amplo mundo da programação de WEB's. Grande abraço e fique em paz amigo.

Comment: Olha eu aqui de novo @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, rsrsrsr... Seguinte, inseri uma página de abertura **(Veja no endereço http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/)** , e quando seleciono qualquer uma das  Categorias, ele me envia para essa nova pagina de abertura. Sem querer abusar, mas já abusando o que eu faço para que isso não aconteça.

Comment: Lá no href onde deixamos assim href="?nome_cat=<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>", acrescente o #produtos depois da categoria, ficando assim: href="?nome_cat=<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>#produtos"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43089/discussion-between-murilo-cabral-and-givanildo-r-de-oliveira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do amigo @Givanildo R. de Oliveira, conseguimos solucionar o problema e trazer somente os produtos referentes a Categoria selecionada.

Abaixo o código funcionando:

```
<?php include "conexao.php"; ?>

<div id="produtos" class="sections full-width-wrapper bg_4">
    <div class="centered-wrapper">

        <div class="section-header">
            <?php include 'menu_pags.php';?>            
        </div>

<div id="produtos-content">

    <!-- Listando os Categorias -->
    <?php
    $nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
    $img_cat = $_POST['img_cat'];
    $query_categoria = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_categoria)){
    ?>
    <div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="cats-list">
        <a class="cat-link" href="?nome_cat=<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>#produtos" title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>">
        <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);"
            src="img_cate/<?php echo $res['img_cat']; ?>" width="100"
            title="<?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?>" />
        </a>
        <div style="background:#2f2140; ; width:880px;z-index:999;border-radius:25px; <?php echo $res['nome_cat']==$_GET['nome_cat'] ? 'display:block;' : ''; ?>" class="single-cat">
            <h1 align="center" style="width:830px; margin-top:-40px;"><?php echo $res['nome_cat']; ?></h1>
            <div style="margin-left:357px;width:50px;" class="cat-links">
                <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                    <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>

<!-- Listando os produtos -->
<?php
$nome_cat = $_GET['nome_cat'];
$query_produtos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome_cat = '$nome_cat'") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query_produtos)){

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$img_prod = $_POST['img_prod'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$nome_cat = $_POST['nome_cat'];
?>

    <div style="float:left; width:112px; height:133px; padding:2px 10px;" id="songs-list">
            <a class="song-link" href="javascript:;" title="">
            <img style="position:relative; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="100" title="<?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>" /></a>

        <div style=" margin-top:120px;z-index:999;border-bottom-right-radius:25px;border-top-right-radius:25px;" class="single-song">
            <div style="width:50px;margin-left:300px;" class="song-links">
            <a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;" title="Voltar">
                <img src="img/fechar.jpg" />
            </a>
                <div class="song-sides">
                    <img style="margin:40px 0 0 -142px;" src="img_prod/<?php echo $res['img_prod']; ?>" width="369" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

            <h1> <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?> </h1>
            <div class="entry" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 100px;">
            <p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; size:14px; font-weight:bold; color:#ccc;">
            <?php echo nl2br($res['descricao']); ?>
            </p>
            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
            <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100px;">
            </div></div></div>
            <span class="song-sides left-side"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>

</div></div></div>
```

Espero que possa ajudar a outros usuários com o mesmo problema.